# Python Tkinter multiple frames with some animation on each frame

Tags: python, memory, tkinter, frame, tkinter-canvas

inspired by Bryan Oakley post [question] [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)
I wrote this program with three pages, each page having an animation: a clock, a measuring device, three bar graphs on the last page.
Following the execution of this program i found that it have an increase in the use of memory and CPU utilization rate, on Windows and on Linux. I use Python 2.7.
I'm sure I'm wrong somewhere but I have not found what to do to keep the memory and the CPU usage percentage at a constant level.
Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    #import tkinter as tk   # python3
    import Tkinter as tk   # python
    import time
    import datetime
    import os
    import random
    from math import *

    TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
    LABPOZ4 = 480
    LABVERT = 5
    if (os.name == 'nt'):
        cale = 'images\\gif\\'
    elif (os.name == 'posix'):
        cale = 'images/gif/'

    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
            # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
            # will be raised above the others
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.frames = {}
            for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
                page_name = F.__name__
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[page_name] = frame

                # put all of the pages in the same location;
                # the one on the top of the stacking order
                # will be the one that is visible.
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame("StartPage")

        def show_frame(self, page_name):
            '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
            frame = self.frames[page_name]
            frame.tkraise()
            #frame.winfo_toplevel().overrideredirect(1)  #pentru teste se comenteaza
            frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("640x480")


    class StartPage(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.controller = controller
            label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            # DATA SI TIMPUL
            DataOra = tk.StringVar()
            DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
            label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
            label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
            label4.place(x=LABPOZ4, y=LABVERT)

            button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage One", height=2, width=10,
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
            button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage Two", height=2, width=10,
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
            button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage Three", height=2, width=10,
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageThree"))
            button1.place(x=100,y=430)
            button2.place(x=200,y=430)
            button3.place(x=300,y=430)

            def afisare():
                date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
                DataOra.set(tmx)
                label4.after(1000,afisare)

            afisare()


    class PageOne(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.controller = controller
            label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            # DATA SI TIMPUL
            DataOra = tk.StringVar()
            DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
            label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
            label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
            label4.place(x=LABPOZ4, y=LABVERT)

            button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\n start page", height=2, width=10,
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
            button.place(x=100,y=430)

                    # CEAS TEST
            def Clock0(w, nx, ny):                                  # clock draw function
                x0 = nx/2; lx = 9*nx/20                             # center and half-width of clock face
                y0 = ny/2; ly = 9*ny/20
                r = 5
                r0 = 0.9 * min(lx,ly)                               # distance of hour labels from center
                r1 = 0.6 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of hour hand
                r2 = 0.8 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of minute hand

                w.create_oval(x0-lx, y0-ly, x0+lx, y0+ly, width=3)  # clock face
                for i in range(1,13):                               # label the clock face
                    phi = pi/6 * i                                  # angular position of label
                    x = x0 + r0 * sin(phi)                          # Cartesian position of label
                    y = y0 - r0 * cos(phi)
                    w.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # hour label

                t = time.localtime()                                # current time
                t_s = t[5]                                          # seconds
                t_m = t[4] + t_s/60                                 # minutes
                t_h = t[3] % 12 + t_m/60                            # hours [0,12]

                phi = pi/6 * t_h                                    # hour hand angle
                x = x0 + r1 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - r1 * cos(phi)                              # draw hour hand
                w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="red", width=5)

                phi = pi/30 * t_m                                   # minute hand angle
                x = x0 + r2 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - r2 * cos(phi)                              # draw minute hand
                w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="blue", width=4)

                phi = pi/30 * t_s                                   # second hand angle
                x = x0 + r2 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - r2 * cos(phi)
                w.create_line(x0, y0 , x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="yellow", width=3)    # draw second hand

                centru_ace = w.create_oval(x0-r,y0-r,x0+r,y0+r, fill="red")

            def Clock(w, nx, ny):                                   # clock callback function
                w.delete(tk.ALL)                                    # delete canvas
                Clock0(w, nx, ny)                                   # draw clock
                w.after(10, Clock, w, nx, ny)                       # call callback after 10 ms

            nx = 250; ny = 250                                      # canvas size
            w = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white")  # create canvas w
            w.place(x=200,y=50)                                     # make canvas visible

            Clock(w, nx, ny)  

            ### END CEAS TEST

            def afisare():
                date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
                DataOra.set(tmx)
                label4.after(1000,afisare)

            afisare()


    class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.controller = controller
            label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            # DATA SI TIMPUL
            DataOra = tk.StringVar()
            DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
            label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
            label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
            label4.place(x=LABPOZ4, y=LABVERT)

            button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\nstart page", height=2, width=10,
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
            button.place(x=100,y=430)

            # APARAT TEST
            global red, bulina
            red = 0
            bulina = 0
            def Aparat0(w, nx, ny, valoare):                        # clock draw function
                global red, bulina
                x0 = nx/2; lx = 9*nx/20                             # center and half-width of clock face
                y0 = ny/2+14; ly = 9*ny/20
                r1 = 0.8 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of indicator

                t_h = valoare                                       # 90 jos, 45 stanga, 180 sus
                phi = pi/6 * t_h                                    # hand angle
                x = x0 + r1 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - r1 * cos(phi)                              # draw hand
                red = w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="red", width=3)
                r = 5
                bulina = w.create_oval(x0-r,y0-r,x0+r,y0+r, fill="red")

            def Aparat(w, nx, ny, valoare):                                   # clock callback function
                global red, bulina
                w.delete(red)                                    # delete canvas
                w.delete(bulina)
                Aparat0(w, nx, ny, valoare)                                   # draw clock
                w.after(5000, Aparat, w, nx, ny, valoare)                      # call callback after 10 ms


            # IMAGINE SCALA APARAT
            photo4 = tk.PhotoImage(file=cale+'scala1.gif')  #scala1.gif
            self.ph1 = photo4

            nx = 350; ny = 350                                      # canvas size
            w = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white")  # create canvas w
            w.create_image(175, 175, image=photo4)
            w.place(x=150,y=50)                                     # make canvas visible

            #Aparat(w, nx, ny, 180)  

            def afisare_Aparat():
                valoare = random.randint(100,270)
                Aparat(w,nx,ny,valoare)
                w.after(5000,afisare_Aparat)

            afisare_Aparat()

            ### END APARAT TEST

            def afisare():
                date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
                DataOra.set(tmx)
                label4.after(1000,afisare)

            afisare()        

    class PageThree(tk.Frame):   # Parametrii AC

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.controller = controller
            label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3", font=TITLE_FONT)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            # DATA SI TIMPUL
            DataOra = tk.StringVar()
            DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
            label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
            label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
            label4.place(x=LABPOZ4, y=LABVERT)        

            button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\nstart page", height=2, width=10,
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
            button.place(x=100,y=430)



            # APARAT TEST
            global red1
            red1 = 0
            bulina1 = 0
            def Aparat01(w1, nx, ny, valoare):     # bar draw function
                global red1
                x0 = 50                             
                y0 = ny                            
                for i in range(0,450,50):
                    x = 20                         # Cartesian position of label
                    y = y0 - i/2 - 5
                    #print y
                    w1.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # value label
                    w1.create_line(x+20, y, x+15, y, fill="black", width=2)

                t_h = valoare                       # valoare

                x = x0 + 20                         # position of head
                y = y0 - t_h                        # draw bar
                red1 = w1.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x, y, fill="red")
                w1.create_line(50, 200, 71, 200, fill="green", width=4)

            def Aparat1(w1, nx, ny, valoare):                       # bar callback function
                global red1
                w1.delete(tk.ALL)                                     # delete canvas
                Aparat01(w1, nx, ny, valoare)                       # draw bar
                w1.after(3000, Aparat1, w1, nx, ny, valoare)        # call callback after 5000 ms

            nx = 70; ny = 350                                       # canvas size
            w1 = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white", relief='ridge') # create canvas
            w1.place(x=150,y=50)                                    # make canvas visible at x,y

            def afisare_Aparat1():
                valoare = random.randint(100,270)
                Aparat1(w1,nx,ny,valoare)
                w1.after(3000,afisare_Aparat1)

            afisare_Aparat1()

            ### END APARAT TEST

            # APARAT TEST1
            global red2
            red2 = 0
            def Aparat02(w2, nx, ny, valoare):      # clock draw function
                global red2
                x0 = 50                             # center and half-width of clock face
                y0 = ny            # length of indicator
                for i in range(0,450,50):
                    x = 20                         # Cartesian position of label
                    y = y0 - i/2 - 5
                    #print y
                    w2.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # value label
                    w2.create_line(x+20, y, x+15, y, fill="black", width=2)

                t_h = valoare                       # 90 jos, 45 stanga, 180 sus

                x = x0 + 20                         # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - t_h                        # draw hand
                red2 = w2.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x, y, fill="blue")
                w2.create_line(50, 200, 71, 200, fill="yellow", width=4)

            def Aparat2(w2, nx, ny, valoare):                       # clock callback function
                global red2
                w2.delete(tk.ALL)                                     # delete canvas
                Aparat02(w2, nx, ny, valoare)                       # draw clock
                w2.after(4000, Aparat2, w2, nx, ny, valoare)        # call callback after 10 ms

            nx2 = 70; ny2 = 350                                      # canvas size
            w2 = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx2, height=ny2, bg = "white", relief='ridge') # create canvas w
            w2.place(x=250,y=50)                                    # make canvas visible

            def afisare_Aparat2():
                valoare = random.randint(100,270)
                Aparat2(w2,nx,ny,valoare)
                w2.after(4000,afisare_Aparat2)

            afisare_Aparat2()

            ### END APARAT TEST1

            # APARAT TEST2
            global red3
            red3 = 0
            def Aparat03(w3, nx, ny, valoare):      # clock draw function
                x0 = 50                             # center and half-width of clock face
                y0 = ny            # length of indicator
                for i in range(0,450,50):
                    x = 20                         # Cartesian position of label
                    y = y0 - i/2 - 5
                    #print y
                    w3.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # value label
                    w3.create_line(x+20, y, x+15, y, fill="black", width=2)

                t_h = valoare                       # 90 jos, 45 stanga, 180 sus

                x = x0 + 20                         # position of arrowhead
                y = y0 - t_h                        # draw hand
                red3 = w3.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x, y, fill="green")
                w3.create_line(50, 200, 71, 200, fill="red", width=4)

            def Aparat3(w3, nx, ny, valoare):                       # clock callback function
                global red3
                w3.delete(tk.ALL)                                     # delete canvas
                Aparat03(w3, nx, ny, valoare)                       # draw clock
                w3.after(5000, Aparat3, w3, nx, ny, valoare)        # call callback after 10 ms

            nx3 = 70; ny3 = 350                                      # canvas size
            w3 = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx3, height=ny3, bg = "white", relief='ridge') # create canvas
            w3.place(x=350,y=50)                                    # make canvas visible 

            def afisare_Aparat3():
                valoare = random.randint(100,270)
                Aparat3(w3,nx,ny,valoare)
                w3.after(5000,afisare_Aparat3)

            afisare_Aparat3()

            ### END APARAT TEST2

            def afisare():
                date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
                DataOra.set(tmx)
                label4.after(1000,afisare)

            afisare()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = SampleApp()
        app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The 'M' part is missing in this question: [mcve]. I'd recommend you use PyCharm to debug your code to see what's up. But to expect someone to debug the whole code, that's a bit...too much to request

Comment: Have you tried omitting one of the pages to see if it changes anything? That would help you narrow down the problem to one particular page. You're updating the 100 times a second. Is that really necessary? Why not just once per second?  Why are you deleting the hands of the clock and recreating them, instead of just moving them?

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. Your code inspire me. I will try to follow your advices, to see what generate the problem. I'm new in Python, and may be I do not understand very well how to do animation with Tkinter on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem. Here's the right code, if someone will be interested. I have simplified the code as much as possible. Thanks, for yours advice.

```
#import tkinter as tk   # python3
import Tkinter as tk   # python
import time
import datetime
import os
import random
from math import *

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        #frame.winfo_toplevel().overrideredirect(1)  #pentru teste se comenteaza
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("640x480")


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # DATA SI TIMPUL
        DataOra = tk.StringVar()
        DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
        label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
        label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
        label4.place(x=480, y=5)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage One", height=2, width=10,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage Two", height=2, width=10,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to\nPage Three", height=2, width=10,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageThree"))
        button1.place(x=100,y=430)
        button2.place(x=200,y=430)
        button3.place(x=300,y=430)

        def afisare():
            date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
            DataOra.set(tmx)
            label4.after(1000,afisare)

        afisare()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # DATA SI TIMPUL
        DataOra = tk.StringVar()
        DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
        label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
        label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
        label4.place(x=430, y=5)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\n start page", height=2, width=10,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.place(x=100,y=430)

        # CEAS TEST
        global line1, line2, line3
        line1 = 0; line2 = 0; line3 = 0
        def Clock0(w, nx, ny):                                  # clock draw function
            global line1, line2, line3
            x0 = nx/2; lx = 9*nx/20                             # center and half-width of clock face
            y0 = ny/2; ly = 9*ny/20
            r = 5
            r0 = 0.9 * min(lx,ly)                               # distance of hour labels from center
            r1 = 0.6 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of hour hand
            r2 = 0.8 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of minute hand

            w.create_oval(x0-lx, y0-ly, x0+lx, y0+ly, width=3)  # clock face
            for i in range(1,13):                               # label the clock face
                phi = pi/6 * i                                  # angular position of label
                x = x0 + r0 * sin(phi)                          # Cartesian position of label
                y = y0 - r0 * cos(phi)
                w.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # hour label

            t = time.localtime()                                # current time
            t_s = t[5]                                          # seconds
            t_m = t[4] + t_s/60                                 # minutes
            t_h = t[3] % 12 + t_m/60                            # hours [0,12]

            phi = pi/6 * t_h                                    # hour hand angle
            x = x0 + r1 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
            y = y0 - r1 * cos(phi)                              # draw hour hand
            line1 = w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="red", width=5, tag='ceas')
            w.coords(line1, x0, y0, x, y)

            phi = pi/30 * t_m                                   # minute hand angle
            x = x0 + r2 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
            y = y0 - r2 * cos(phi)                              # draw minute hand
            line2 = w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="blue", width=4, tag='ceas')
            w.coords(line2, x0, y0, x, y)

            phi = pi/30 * t_s                                   # second hand angle
            x = x0 + r2 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
            y = y0 - r2 * cos(phi)
            line3 = w.create_line(x0, y0 , x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="yellow", width=3, tag='ceas')
            w.coords(line3, x0, y0, x, y)

            centru_ace = w.create_oval(x0-r,y0-r,x0+r,y0+r, fill="red")

        def Clock(w, nx, ny):                                   # clock callback function
            global line1, line2, line3
            w.delete('ceas')                                    # delete canvas
            Clock0(w, nx, ny)
            #w.coords(line1, 100,100,200,200)                         # draw clock
            #w.coords(line2, 100,100,200,200)
            #w.coords(line3, 100,100,200,200)
            w.after(10, Clock, w, nx, ny)                       # call callback after 10 ms

        nx = 250; ny = 250                                      # canvas size
        w = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white")  # create canvas w
        w.place(x=200,y=50)                                     # make canvas visible

        Clock(w, nx, ny)  

        ### END CEAS TEST

        def afisare():
            date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
            DataOra.set(tmx)
            label4.after(1000,afisare)

        afisare()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # DATA SI TIMPUL
        DataOra = tk.StringVar()
        DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
        label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
        label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
        label4.place(x=480, y=5)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\nstart page", height=2, width=10,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.place(x=100,y=430)

        # APARAT TEST
        global red, bulina
        red = 0
        bulina = 0
        def Aparat0(w, nx, ny, valoare):                        # scale draw function
            global red, bulina
            x0 = nx/2; lx = 9*nx/20                             # center and half-width of clock face
            y0 = ny/2+14; ly = 9*ny/20
            r1 = 0.8 * min(lx,ly)                               # length of indicator

            t_h = valoare                                       # 90 jos, 45 stanga, 180 sus
            phi = pi/6 * t_h                                    # hand angle
            x = x0 + r1 * sin(phi)                              # position of arrowhead
            y = y0 - r1 * cos(phi)                              # draw hand
            red = w.create_line(x0, y0, x, y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="red", width=3)
            r = 5
            bulina = w.create_oval(x0-r,y0-r,x0+r,y0+r, fill="red")

        def Aparat(w, nx, ny, valoare):                                   # callback function
            global red, bulina
            w.delete(red)                                    # delete red, bulina
            w.delete(bulina)
            Aparat0(w, nx, ny, valoare)                                   # draw clock
            #####w.after(5000, Aparat, w, nx, ny, valoare) ###### PROBLEM !!!

        nx = 350; ny = 350                                      # canvas size
        w = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white")  # create canvas w
        w.place(x=150,y=50)                                     # make canvas visible

        #Aparat(w, nx, ny, 180)  

        def afisare_Aparat():
            valoare = random.randint(100,270)
            Aparat(w,nx,ny,valoare)
            w.after(1000,afisare_Aparat)

        afisare_Aparat()

        ### END APARAT TEST

        def afisare():
            date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
            DataOra.set(tmx)
            label4.after(1000,afisare)

        afisare()        

class PageThree(tk.Frame):   # Parametrii AC

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # DATA SI TIMPUL
        DataOra = tk.StringVar()
        DataOra.set('2016-04-06 16:20:00')
        label4 = tk.Label(self,  textvariable=DataOra, fg='blue', bg='white', relief="ridge", width=20)
        label4.config(font=('courier', 10, 'bold'))
        label4.place(x=480, y=5)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the\nstart page", height=2, width=10,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.place(x=100,y=430)



        # APARAT TEST
        def Aparat01(w1, nx, ny, valoare):     # bar draw function
            #global red1
            x0 = 50                             
            y0 = ny                            
            for i in range(0,450,50):
                x = 20                         # Cartesian position of label
                y = y0 - i/2 - 5
                #print y
                w1.create_text(x, y, text=str(i))                # value label
                w1.create_line(x+20, y, x+15, y, fill="black", width=2)

            t_h = valoare                       # valoare

            x = x0 + 20                         # position of head
            y = y0 - t_h                        # draw bar
            w1.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x, y, fill="red")
            w1.create_line(50, 200, 71, 200, fill="green", width=4)

        def Aparat1(w1, nx, ny, valoare):                       # bar callback function
            w1.delete(tk.ALL)                                     # delete canvas
            Aparat01(w1, nx, ny, valoare)                       # draw bar
            ######w1.after(3000, Aparat1, w1, nx, ny, valoare) ######  PROBLEM !!!!

        nx = 70; ny = 350                                       # canvas size
        w1 = tk.Canvas(self, width=nx, height=ny, bg = "white", relief='ridge') # create canvas
        w1.place(x=150,y=50)                                    # make canvas visible at x,y

        def afisare_Aparat1():
            valoare = random.randint(100,270)
            Aparat1(w1,nx,ny,valoare)
            w1.after(1000,afisare_Aparat1)

        afisare_Aparat1()

        ### END APARAT TEST

        def afisare():
            date1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            time1=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            tmx= '%s %s' % (date1, time1)
            DataOra.set(tmx)
            label4.after(1000,afisare)

        afisare()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```